# Google Analytics in BigQuery: getting total events for a specific event action and total sessions from the same query

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to get a table with 3 columns:

1. date
2. total events for a specific event action
3. total sessions for the whole site
   This is what I have at the moment:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(format_date('%Y-%m-%d', parse_date("%Y%m%d", date)) AS DATE) as DATE,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN hits.eventinfo.eventaction = 'Add to Cart' THEN hits.eventinfo.eventaction END) AS AddtoCart,
    SUM(totals.visits) AS visits
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) as hits
WHERE
    _table_suffix BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20160815'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date desc
```

The problem is the unnesting of hits seems to multiply my number of sessions, this is what I get without the unnesting:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(format_date('%Y-%m-%d', parse_date("%Y%m%d", date)) AS DATE) as DATE,
    SUM(totals.visits) AS visits
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
WHERE
    _table_suffix BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20160815'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date desc
```

How can I have the 2 in the same table?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a session ID and then count the distinct number of session IDs.

```
SELECT 
    CAST(format_date('%Y-%m-%d', parse_date("%Y%m%d", date)) AS DATE) as DATE,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN hits.eventinfo.eventaction = 'Add to Cart' THEN hits.eventinfo.eventaction END) AS AddtoCart,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS string),CAST(visitId AS string))) AS visits
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
UNNEST(hits) as hits
WHERE
    _table_suffix BETWEEN '20160801' AND '20160815'
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date desc
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is great!
I notice that the sessionID also includes non-interaction sessions but by adding 
`totals.visits = 1` as an extra condition, I match exactly the numbers in GA.
Thanks again!